# video capture software for iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone

HI All,
I m looking for a software/tool, which can lead me to capture my application in simulator..
I saw so many videos of application, which performs their functionality of application and capture it in video.

Please suggest me some video capturing tool for my app promotion.

Suggestions are always appreciated.
regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [What tool(s) can I use to produce iPhone App Screencasts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935540/what-tools-can-i-use-to-produce-iphone-app-screencasts)

Comment: OS X has it built-in, go to File -> Screen Recording menu in QuickTime Player 10

Answer (score 26):

The perfect tool is **iPhone-Simulator-Capture** SIMBL plugin

1. Install [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php)
2. Download the [code](https://github.com/davbeck/iPhone-Simulator-Capture)
3. Modify Info.plist key "SIMBLTargetApplications/MaxBundleVersion" (*and/or "SIMBLTargetApplications/MinBundleVersion"*) value plist to the actual version of your simulator (240 worked for me) (*latest version: 272*)
4. Build
5. Place bundle in “~/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins"
6. Relaunch simulator, now you should have "Recording" in the menu.

Comment: (Download the code) link not working......

Comment: I get the following error. "iOS Simulator 5.0 (v272) has not been tested with the plugin iPhone Simulator Capture 1.1.2 (v1). As a precaution, it has not been loaded. Please contact the plugin developer for further information." Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: If it shows error for path of SIMBL, just copy “/Library/Application Support/SIMBL” to “~/Library/Application Support/SIMBL”

Comment: I've tried a few screen recorders now, and this one gives the best results by far. Thanks!

Comment: actually it was minbundleversion i had to change apparently, not maxbundleversion?

Comment: hi! I have builded this source and get this error: ln: /Users/alexander/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/iPhone Simulator Capture.bundle: No such file or directory. I have XCode 4.3.   Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Is it possible to record video in iPhone Landscape and iPad ?

Comment: The Readme at github sais: "Deprecated - This project is no longer maintained"

Answer (score 23):

Now the easiest way is using QuickTime with **File > New screen recording** and select the part of your screen you want to capture.

iMovie is doing the rest well :-)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is genius! so simple.

Comment: Great, although I got no sound... hm

Answer (score 3):

As I could not find any tool fitting my needs, I made my own tool : WhazzerFinger.
You can download it (sources or binary) here: https://github.com/zippy1978/WhazzerFinger.

The application adds an overlay on top of the actual simulator window to give it a more realistic look. At the moment only iPhone is supported in portrait or landscape mode. iPad should come in the next releases.

Screenshots and videos are stored on the desktop. Videos are encoded using H.264 codec.

Here is a resulting video (WhazzerFinger + iMovie with Ken Burns effect): http://youtu.be/Z3W-qU5EP4A.

Comment: I built/launched your app from Xcode. It brings the simulator to the front (if running), but the app itself has no menu or icon in the dock, and no clue as to how to start/end capture, or where the movies are saved. Not very friendly...

Comment: The app icon shows in the system top menu bar. Screenshots and videos are saved on the desktop.

Comment: I tried to record a home screen of iOS simulator using your tool, but the resulting video is blank and has dimensions 21 by 21 pixels. So it does not work for OS X 10.9.2

Answer (score 2):

Any Mac OS screen capture tool will work, such as QuickTime Player or Snapz Pro X from Ambrosia Software, Inc.

The QuickTime Player screen recordings are of your entire screen, so you should be prepared to crop the video.  If you don't have sufficient video editing software, Snapz Pro would be the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm) for some times now and I'm satisfied with the performance. It captures the whole screen but you can crop the video afterwards in Screenflow.

One big advantage is the possibility to exchange the cursor with a custom image (like a white circle) so it looks more like a touch.

Answer (score 1):

I installed iPhone Simulator Capture today. With SIMBL installation it works. But it displayed an alert window on every simulator first run. My version is 272. I downloaded latest source from the Github. Build the code and replaced the bundle file that xcode created with the file under Library/Application Support/SIMBL. So it is working now. No version test alert window.

Comment: hi can u help me to capture video using SIMPL

Comment: Follow the instructions from here [link](https://github.com/davbeck/iPhone-Simulator-Capture)