# Screen Capture Making Video

Tags: iphone

Can anyone know how to make video recording by capture the screen on iphone? I have an animation and other audio that is working simultaneously with same time and I want to record it as a video so that I can post this video to

Comment: Hope the tutorial [here](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673) will solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

You can't capture video from the iPhone screen, but you have a number of options for capturing video from the simulator. See this question for details: [video capture software for iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183768/video-capture-software-for-iphone-simulator).