# Does the iOS Simulator support custom plugins?

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios-simulator

does anyone know if iOS Simulator (that goes with XCode) support any kind of plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iOS simulator has no public API for plugins.

Comment: But in practice it supports plugins. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6073071/326017