# iPad/iPod Demo and tutorial videos - What tool

Tags: ipad, screen, video-recording

I'd like to take screen movies of my iPad/iPod apps to show my customers. Is there one that will grab the display of the iSimulator?

An added bonus would be a screen recording feature too, but that is not critical.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What tool(s) can I use to produce iPhone App Screencasts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935540/what-tools-can-i-use-to-produce-iphone-app-screencasts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are online screencasting tools available for recording purposes and they are good. I have used http://screentoaster.com but looks like they are no more. I guess you have a couple of options

- http://www.screencast-o-matic.com (online tool)
- Jing: http://www.techsmith.com/jing/ (installation required)
- CamStudio: http://camstudio.org/ (installation required)