# Capture iPhone Screen From My App and record Video

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, cydia, video-recording

I am just curious to create an app which records video of iphone screen or capture images of iphone screen.  I know that Apple doesn't allow such kinds of apps on the app store and I have no intention of doing that. I can upload my app on **Cydia** if I want, but my current objective is just to develop an app with the capabilities of capturing video of the iphone scree n or taking screen shot of device.

Let's say that I am playing a game and I want to record it so I can show my friend how well I can play. If the game itself has some option to record video (which generally is not available) than that would be great.  I want to develop that kind of feature.

I am interested to know how to do this in **jailbreak** devices. Similar to the **Display Recorder** app from Cydia.

**EDIT:**

I want to capture the screen with a 5 sec delay.. I minimize my app and enter a game, then the screen shot will be of that game. Regardless which app is running it just needs to capture a screenshot of the iDevice's screen.

Comment: Are you sure you wanna discuss here how to make apps with restricted behavior? As developer, I am interested in "right" apps, and users not to use jailbroken devices, and no Cydia or other dangerous stuff. Yes, dangerous. If I were a businessman, I would never use a jailbroken one. But, well, that's me.

Comment: If not here than plz let me know what is the right place for this.. and I am just curious how to do this.. as I told in question I am not intended to distribute the app.

Comment: Here is an article regarding the way how to run apps in background. If you achieve this, you can take screenshots (but not sure, and less sure about the video capturing). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547477/how-to-run-my-application-in-background-in-iphone P.S.: Consider I have never read your post.

Comment: Kapil, here is a fine place to post this question.  There's not **a lot** of jailbreak developers who answer questions here, but it doesn't hurt to ask.  Disregard Sava's irrelevant comments about what **he/she** is interested in.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can take screenShot using this code..

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.window.frame.size);
    [BackView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: thanks @Rajneesh071.. You can read my question once again.. I don't want to capture screenshot of my app I want to capture screen of iphone. There may be some other app running and I want to take video or snap of that app from my App. So in short need to capture whatever is displaying on iphone

Comment: If you got the answer of this then plz inform me...:)

Comment: hey..it is possible if we can take screenshot of iphone screen...instead of our app view..

Comment: thats what I am asking how to take screenshot of iphone screen instead of app view?

Answer (score -1):

I have done for my client who wanted. I also recorded video for Facebook screenCast for app review.

All your need is:

An iOS device running iOS 8 or later
A Mac running OS X Yosemite or later
Lightning cable (the cable that comes with iOS devices)

No need for jailbreak, a third party app or additional hardware.

Here are the steps to do it:

1. Connect your iPhone or iPad to your Mac via the lightning cable
2. Open **QuickTime player**
3. Click File then select ‘New Movie Recording’
4. A recording window will appear (with you in it, most likely). Click the little arrow of the drop down menu in front of the record button, then select your iPhone or iPad
5. Click the Record button. Now perform the tasks on your iOS device that you want to record. AND SAVE.

[Here is the link for more ways:](http://www.apptamin.com/blog/capture-iphone-ipad-screen-video/)

Answer (score -1):

@Kapil.. To achieve this, privates apis can be used. But obviously, apple does not allow it. So your app will get Rejected. If you are doing this for personal use, then you can use apis like IOSurface. 
Hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score -3):

Just simply hold the power button and home button at the same time and you can see the captured screen inside your photo album.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but as you can read my question I am asking how to do it programmatically.

Comment: @Wax it would turn his iphone off.Not take a picture.