# How to record a movie from iPhone Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool(s) can I use to produce iPhone App Screencasts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935540/what-tools-can-i-use-to-produce-iphone-app-screencasts)

I've heard there are ways to record movies from the iPhone Simulator. I realize there are [possibly thousands of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253993/how-to-record-a-screencast-from-the-iphone-simulator), but which one is the most straight-forward, taking the least effort to set up?

Comment: Any screen casting tool will do. I used ScreenFlow for my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way how to record iOS simulator is [Sound Stage](http://soundstageapp.com/)

Its only $5 and can do really nice videos....

Comment: Thanks x 1000 for pointing out Sound Stage!

Comment: When I open the link in the Mac App Store, it says the application is no longer for sale.

Comment: Beware – it doesn't support iPhone 5, nor any of iPad screens.