# ios:Whats the best way to capture ios simulator activity and convert it into avi or quicktime movie programatically?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, quicktime

I have an app which plays take static images and does animation. I want to capture the video while app is running and convert it into quiktime movie file or avi file.

Whats would be best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why does it need to be programmatic? If you're running it in the Simulator anyway, you can just use one of the many tools for capturing screencasts from it that are mentioned in this question: [What tool(s) can I use to produce iPhone App Screencasts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935540/what-tools-can-i-use-to-produce-iphone-app-screencasts)

Comment: This link helped a lot.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061092/make-movie-file-with-picture-array-and-song-file-using-avasset

Answer (score 2):

It won't be programmatic and you'll have to crop it, but you could use QuickTime to record a screencast.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061092/make-movie-file-with-picture-array-and-song-file-using-avasset. This was good find