# How to record a video of a running iOS app for promotional use?

Tags: ios, video-recording

I need to know how to record a video of an iOS app running for promotional use. Could anybody please help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What tool(s) can I use to produce iPhone App Screencasts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935540/what-tools-can-i-use-to-produce-iphone-app-screencasts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.  If you want to run your app using the iOS Simulator, then you can use audio/video screen capture software such as http://camstudio.org/ or http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html.

If you need to record a video of the app running on the iOS device, then that would require a slightly more complicated setup.  You will need Apple TV http://www.apple.com/appletv/ and a DVR.  You would connect the Apple TV to a DVR, then from the DVR you would run an output cable to a TV or monitor.  The iPhone and Apple TV needs to be configured for **mirroring**.  Afterwards, you should be able to project and see your iOS app running on the screen (over Wi-Fi) while you are recording the running iOS app on the DVR.

Answer (score 7):

Now, with OSX Yosemite, Quick Time Player has a build-in feature that records your iPhone screen.

- Connect your phone with your Lightning cable to your mac
- Open Quick Time
- File > New Record
- This will open your webcam stream, but you can select the source on the right of the record button: just choose your iPhone.
- Record.

Comment: Great!!  I had been struggling to record footage for an app preview and this new feature is so simple and easy to use.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest this app http://soundstageapp.com/

It captures the app operation in video and provides tools for entire production of the promo video.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only do this on a jailbroken iOS device. Google for ScreenRecorder.