# How do I take a video version of screenshot on iPod Touch 4th Gen?

Tags: ios6, screenshot, ipod-touch

I want to create videos of myself doing app demos on my iPod, how do I create a video version of screen shot?

Comment: Are these your applications? If so, you can just run them in the Simulator and do what's described in the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935540/what-tools-can-i-use-to-produce-iphone-app-screencasts . Otherwise, you might be able to craft something along these lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090184/how-does-the-ios-app-display-recorder-record-the-screen-without-using-private-ap

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way too take screen videos. You could just take a screen shot of the screen every time you change the screen, and perhaps edit the photo to show what you changed. Apple should definitely make a way to create screen videos.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to screenshot a video. But you could always take a picture of the video by pressing the home button and the lock button at the same time. Good luck!